# Condition for strong law of large numbers : Understanding the solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading the solution of the following task:

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

From where does the last inequality in the second line comes from? Everything else is totally clear to me.

Comment: The solution reproduced in the question is bogus. In particular the inequality you ask about does not hold: consider that the numerator is at least $1$ hence the fraction is at least of order $1/n$, which cannot be dominated by $1/n^{3/2}$. The proof of the result itself is classical, and uses Borel-Cantelli lemma, but on the events $A_n=[X_n\ne0]$, not the ones in the question.

Comment: Cannot resist to note that you accepted a solution 23 minutes after it was posted. *As we can see, this has consequences...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the sum with an integral:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{-3/2} = 1+\sum_{i=2}^n i^{-3/2} \leq 1+\int_1^n x^{-3/2}\ dx$$
*Edit:* As @Did correctly notes, the stated inequality (which is incorrect) does not follow from this.

Comment: So the sum is finite, okay. But why there is a $n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ remaining on the ride side of the inequality?

Comment: Sorry, putting $\infty$ for the upper limits was a typo: we get a better bound if we use $n$ instead.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)

Comment: Probably a stupid question: Where does this inequality between a sum and an integral comes from?

Comment: Whoops, there was another mistake that I just fixed. How it works is that since $x^{-3/2}$ is a decreasing function we have $i^{-3/2}=\int_{i-1}^{i} i^{-3/2}\ dx \leq \int_{i-1}^i x^{-3/2}\ dx$. It follows then that $\sum_{i=2}^n i^{-3/2} = \sum_{i=2}^n \int_{i-1}^i x^{-3/2}\ dx=\int_1^n x^{-3/2}\ dx$.

Comment: All this does not yield the inequality in the question (which happens to be wrong).